# Flatten list of list of strings

Tags: python, list

I have this list:

```
list1 = ["['word']", "['second', 'first']", "['first']"]
```

You can see it's not exactly a list of list of strings as the items were converted into strings.

I want to have this flattened output:

```
list2 = ['word', 'second', 'first', 'first']
```

Just a simple list of strings.

I 've tried using this way:

```
list2 = [ x.strip('[]') for x in list1]
```

But the issue is with the second item still considered as one item:

```
["'word'", "'second', 'first'", "'first'"]
```

So I tried splitting by comma:

```
list3 = [item.split(',') for x in list2 for item in x]
```

But it gave this output:

```
[["'"],
 ['w'],
 ['o'],
 ['r'],
 ['d'],
 ["'"],
 ["'"],
 ['s'],
 ['e'],
 ['c'],
 ['o'],
 ['n'],
 ['d'],
 ["'"],
 ['', ''],
 [' '],
 ["'"],
 ['f'],
 ['i'],
 ['r'],
 ['s'],
 ['t'],
 ["'"],
 ["'"],
 ['f'],
 ['i'],
 ['r'],
 ['s'],
 ['t'],
 ["'"]]
```

Any idea how to fix this?

### UPDATES - SOLUTION

With help from @AKX

```
list2 = [ast.literal_eval(item) for item in list1]
```

Then using this function:

```
def flatten(lst):
    for el in lst:
        if isinstance(el, list):
            yield from el
        else:
            yield el

list3 = flatten(list2)
list(list3)
```

This gives:

```
['word', 'second', 'first', 'first']
```

### UPDATE 2

An optimized and alternative solution from @waynelpu instead of *flatten* function, just use:

```
list2 = [inner for item in list1 for inner in ast.literal_eval(item)]
```

Comment: How about fixing whatever generated that mess in the first place?  How was that list generated?  Fix that instead of trying to undo it.

Comment: It's data from external APIs, you can nothing about it except consuming it.

Comment: Can you file a bug?  It looks like the implementation is returning `str(somelist)` for the items.  If the API was returning JSON strings it would make more sense, but that syntax isn't JSON, it is Python code as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list of strings of Python expressions that represent lists (how's that for a nested clause), you will have to use `ast.literal_eval()` to get back to reality, as it were.

```
>>> import ast
>>> list1 = ["['word']", "['second', 'first']", "['first']"]
>>> list2 = [ast.literal_eval(item) for item in list1]
[['word'], ['second', 'first'], ['first']]
```

Using `ast.literal_eval()`, as opposed to the **dangerous** `eval()` **that you shouldn't use** is safe, as it only evaluates literals that can have no side effects.

Comment: you just need to flatten it, list2 = [inner for item in list1 for inner in ast.literal_eval(item)]

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = ["['word']", "['second', 'first']", "['first']"]
new_lst = [sub_val for val in list1 for sub_val in eval(val)]
print new_lst

Result:['word', 'second', 'first', 'first']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [more_itertools.flatten](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.flatten)

```
from more_itertools import flatten
import ast

list1 = ["['word']", "['second', 'first']", "['first']"]
list(flatten(ast.literal_eval(item) for item in list1))
```

Output:

```
['word', 'second', 'first', 'first']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution:

```
import re
list1 = ["['word']", "['second', 'first']", "['first']"]
pattern = re.compile(r'\w+')
m = pattern.findall(str(list1))
```

Result:

```
['word', 'second', 'first', 'first']
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to flatten everything use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> import ast
>>> list1 = ["['word']", "['second', 'first']", "['first']"]
>>> list2 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(ast.literal_eval, list1)))
>>> list2
['word', 'second', 'first', 'first']
```