# Split string within double quotes in list in optimized way?

Tags: python, list, optimization, split, python-3.6

Here the **Input**

```
['not,equal','gold,copy','equity','ex','influence']
```

after applying some functionalities like split and replace

the **Output** like this

```
['not','equal','gold','copy','equity','ex','influence']
```

the problem was, If I enter more input it will take more time to change like that output. I applied for loop. Is there any possible way to optimize?

```
   tag=input()
   tag_list=[]
   tag_list.append(tag)
   print(tag_list) 
   hi=[]

    for i in range(len(tag_list)):
         hi.append(tag_list[i].split(',')) 
        print(hi)
```

Comment: Can you paste your code please?

Comment: `tag=input()
tag_list=[]
tag_list.append(tag)
print(tag_list)
hi=[]
for i in range(len(tag_list)):
    hi.append(tag_list[i].split(','))
print(hi)`

Comment: In that, I did not added replace function

Comment: Please add your code in your question, thanks

Comment: Probably yes, you can try one of the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52981376/flatten-list-of-list-of-strings/52981969

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `['not,equal','gold,copy','equity','ex','influence']` is your input to `input()` method, use `ast` module's `literal_eval` method to convert into python list.

I used list comprehensions while splitting tags and `functool` to flatten the list

```py
import operator
import functools
import ast

tag = input() # ['not,equal','gold,copy','equity','ex','influence']
tag_list = ast.literal_eval(tag)
# tag_list.append(tag)
print("tag_list: ", tag_list)

hi = [tags.split(",") for tags in tag_list]
print("hi: ", hi)
hi_flatten = functools.reduce(operator.concat, hi)
print("hi_flatten: ", hi_flatten)
```

Output:

```
tag_list:  ['not,equal', 'gold,copy', 'equity', 'ex', 'influence']
hi:  [['not', 'equal'], ['gold', 'copy'], ['equity'], ['ex'], ['influence']]
hi_flatten:  ['not', 'equal', 'gold', 'copy', 'equity', 'ex', 'influence']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try list comprehensions:

```
input_ = ['not,equal','gold,copy','equity','ex','influence']
output = [item for item in [i.split(",") for i in input_] for item in item]
```

Result:

```
['not', 'equal', 'gold', 'copy', 'equity', 'ex', 'influence']
```

The list comprehension is equivalent to:

```
input_ = ['not,equal','gold,copy','equity','ex','influence']
output = []
for item in input_:
    for sub_item in item.split(","):
        output.append(sub_item)
```